# What is importance of the reflow profile?

Tags: mpu6050

I was reading the MPU6050 datasheet to understand all the type of errors that affect the accelerometer, after finding information on the Reflow Profile i look up on wikipedia the [Reflow Soldering Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflow_soldering)

As a noob i can't understand the importance, initially i though it was correlated with the temperature effect on the accelerometer bias, but i was wrong.

**Why is important?**

**How do you read this values?(or when you use this data)**
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is not an Arduino question, it's an electronics assembly process question which would belong not here, but on electronics.stackexchange.com however it has already been asked and answered multiple times there.  Realistically most Arduino enthusiasts would buy this chip already on a board.  If you want to deal with the bare part for non-critical prototypes, skilled use of a hot air wand usually produces an acceptable outcome. If you are going for automated assembly, you would discuss this with your assembly provider; actually programming a reflow oven is far beyond the scope of things here.

Comment: Sorry for that,my mistake, i read now this [link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the idea to post this question here was to give the possibility to find information on this section about to the relevance or not to understand this concept related to Arduino. Before posting here i searched on electronics.stackexchange.com but i didn't find a suitable question, now i am studying [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27573/why-and-when-to-use-reflow-soldering/27578#27578) for example  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The reflow profile is of no interest to the end user - only to the manufacturer building a PCB. You don't need to know or understand it unless you are becoming a PCB manufacturer.

Comment: You use solder to attach components to a PCB. Reflowing is a specific soldering technique, manufacturers of components will specify which heating/cooling pattern will match the component(s). This having said, it's probably irrelevant to you, but atleast you now know why :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Majenko  Paul Yep my question was offtopic, sorry for that. The story is the following: i went to a Fablab in Rome, with no previous experience, they suggest me  for a deep understanding on how Arduino works with an accelerometer to read all the datasheet, i was studiyng the "Sensitivity Scale Factor Variation Over Temperature" and arrived to the reflow profile, i made a mistake :) Thanks for your time, and sorry again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reflow soldering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflow_soldering) is an assembly process for printed circuit boards (PCBs) in which surface-mount parts are placed on a PCB prepared with solder paste.  The solder is melted by heating in a temperature-controlled oven, which then electrically connects component leads to pads on the PCB.  ICs can be damaged by high temperatures/rapid changes in temperatures, so the thermal profile defines the acceptable limits on the temperature of the reflow to avoid damaging the component.